# Android application support multiple screen sizes

Tags: android

I created an application that can run on multiple screen sizes. My application runs on normal, large, and x-large screen sizes, but my application does not work on small phones . Its UI is not displaying in full on small phones. Please tell me any solution.

```
  <supports-screens 
                  android:smallScreens="true"
                  android:normalScreens="true"
                  android:largeScreens="true" 
                  android:xlargeScreens="true"
                  android:anyDensity="true"
                  android:largestWidthLimitDp="720"
                  android:compatibleWidthLimitDp="720" />
```

Comment: Define your problem clearly. Does your application run or not on small screens. If It doesn't show full UI it means that you have to fix your UI. Change your activity layout files so it looks ok on small screens.

Answer (score 0):

Make use of below tag in manifest to filter out small phones :

```
<supports-screens android:resizeable=["true"| "false"]
              android:smallScreens=["true" | "false"]
              android:normalScreens=["true" | "false"]
              android:largeScreens=["true" | "false"]
              android:xlargeScreens=["true" | "false"]
              android:anyDensity=["true" | "false"]
              android:requiresSmallestWidthDp="integer"
              android:compatibleWidthLimitDp="integer"
              android:largestWidthLimitDp="integer"/>
```

where :

```
android:smallScreens="false"
```

For More info :

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/supports-screens-element.html

Other way is you can have a check in your code.

While launching the application, check for the screen size and if the screen size is less than your desired size, show a message and exit from the application.

The former method will work for filtering the application in google play, but the later one will be a good option I think eventhough I didnt find anyone using such a method (Good if user tries to install your application offline...means not from google play).

Answer (score 0):

```
DisplayMetrics metrics = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
           Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "density-"+metrics.density,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
           if(metrics.density==1.5)
                tv.setTextSize(size);
           else if(metrics.density==2.0)
                   tv.setTextSize(size);
           else if(metrics.density==3.0)
                  tv.setTextSize(size);
```

With this you can find out what density your small device is then according to it you can set the size for your textview

Answer (score 0):

Specifying 'android-smallscreens="true" ' will make it available for small screens. It wont exactly help in solving your problem. To make your app usable for all kinds of devices, here are the points taken from android developer resource.

- Provide different layouts for different screen sizes.The configuration qualifiers you can use to provide size-specific resources are small, normal, large, and xlarge.
- Provide different bitmap drawables for different screen densities
- do not give hard coded pixel values
- try to use relative layout instead of absolute.

Check out [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can use different layout folder for small screen

for example for 240x320 screen you can take seperate folder inside resources name as

```
layout-320x240
```

and put same xml inside folder.